# magnetic effect in scrollView

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am displaying a series of images in a (vertical) ScrollView. The idea is that it resembles some kind of thumbwheel. 
I would like to have the scrollView "stop" or "click" at certain intervals, like it 'captures' the nearest position with a magnetic effect. You see this magnetic capture effect many times in image galleries.

Are there any specific attributes to this scrollview that enables this effect?
Probably not, because I searched this intensively. But ya never know...

If not, is it possible to implement this in Java code?

Or any other tips - perhaps not using ScrollView?

Comment: Sounds like a Gallery but vertical :) .

Comment: Do you have any code of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RealViewSwitcher](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html). It should work the way you want after a few modifications

Comment: Thanks for this tip. But all that is really one by one picture. What I am looking for is a wheel like a fruit machine (*bar*bar*bar*) effect. You see more pictures on the wheel than just one, at least three.

Comment: I saw a similar effect lately in a date picker: you scroll some sort of wheel up or down, and it locks on a full day, never in between two days. That's what I need! Only with pictures. Get the picture?

Comment: which idea brings me to the following link! 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/building-a-slot-machine-in-android-viewflipper-meet-gesture-detector/1598

Comment: Further Googling brought to me the following link to check:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

surely this must be it!!!